# Regex Replace exact matching ( include special character )

Tags: c#

I have a string;

```
string input = "John + Daniels";
```

I want to replace the word `" + Daniels"` with a space.

like this: `input = "John";`

https://dotnetfiddle.net/bakGp9

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
string input = "John + Daniels";
        
string withSpecialCharacter = string.Concat("\b" + " + Daniels" + "\b");
    
StringBuilder tempString = new StringBuilder();
tempString.AppendFormat(@"{0}", withSpecialCharacter);
string finalString = tempString.ToString();
        

string result = Regex.Replace(input, finalString, "");
        

Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

but Replace doesn't work.
output = "John + Daniels";

Comment: what is wrong with `input.Replace(" + Daniels", "");`?

Comment: Why does this need Regex at all?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk input.Replace doesn't provide an exact match. if input ="John Danielss" output is like this "John s";

Comment: @tomclack where did you specify it in the question?

Comment: @tomclack do you need to leave only the first word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your verbatim input to [`Regex.Escape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-7.0) in order to appropriately escape it for use in a pattern. Make sure to use verbatim string literals (`@"..."`) for the `\b` escape sequence:

```
string pattern = @"\b" + Regex.Escape(" + Daniels") + @"\b";
// ...
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");
```

Comment: why do you need `Concat` and Regex to just replace `"John + Daniels"`  to `"John"`?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk copied from OP, updated now

Comment: ok, why do you need Regex?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76457457/regex-replace-exact-matching-include-special-character/76457496?noredirect=1#comment134814028_76457457

Comment: did you try to run your code?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen not working.

Comment: I did not, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: how will replacing `Concat` with `+` change the situation?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk What are you talking about? `@"..."` and `Regex.Escape` is gonna "change the situation". https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRj1UwAJUCA6AFQFMAPYSgJVoHMIAbAQzAFF6ABzC0AzqICWAeyiiA3MQJkJUQRGCkAvKQBEAKSkALKKUSkAItygTanUToX4lpQd2DBaYE9tSodAHQAjHVNSVjYGSj5RAGNuQVoAChCzS2tbewBKUN8A4McAegLSSlLFMhFRLg1tcMjWQR4YpJU1YBgXNw8vDp0dTMdFAE5EyuqBoA

Comment: @tomclack Try again

Comment: I'm talking about `Concat ` that you had before I asked why you need this, and `+`